# How can I tell my manager that I completed the work he assigned?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am learning English and feeling very difficulty in framing sentence. I need following sentences into proper sentence please help me in this.

Yesterday my manager as assigned some work to do and today I completed that work.  I have to inform my manager that I completed the task and attached the documents regarding assignment.

Comment: For the record, do not ask a question here **and** on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145259). And do not expect that a question here will necessarily be answered here within a matter of [minutes](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145259/how-to-tell-my-manger-i-completed-the-work-he-as-assigned#comment299090_145259).

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting your question as to how to inform your manager  you have done what he asked you to do. Hence,

> I've completed the work/task/project/assignment you required and attached the necessary
>   documents.

Comment: I would probably use the word _assigned_ instead of _required_, and I'd include an extra "have": _I've completed the work/task/project you assigned and have attached the necessary documents._ (This doesn't mean I disagree with your answer; it simply means there is more than one way to say just about anything, and some of it will inevitably come down to stylistic preferences.)

Answer (score 1):

As I answered on the other site already, a simple solution is almost what you wrote:

> Dear [manager], I completed the task and attached the documents related to the assignment.

If you want to elaborate a bit, you could write something like:

> Dear [manager],
>
> I have finished the assignment you gave me yesterday.
>   Please find attached the documents I prepared for this assignment.
>
> Kind regards, Praveen

Comment: "...and attached the documents regarding the assignment" doesn't sound quite right. Perhaps use "relating to" rather than "regarding". Also, because you're attaching the documents to the e-mail now, rather than in the past, it should be simple present. Hence: "...and attach the documents relating to the assignment."

Comment: It's probably a matter of opinion, but "assignment" sounds like something you're given to do at school. Perhaps "task" is better in a work environment.

Comment: I have heard assignment being used in out-of-school contexts a lot among my Indian colleagues, so I have to admit I do not stumble on that anymore :) As for "regarding", yes, maybe your suggestion works a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer an edited version of your whole question just in case that helps; your English is pretty clear already!

> I am learning English and experiencing a lot of difficulty in framing a sentence. I need to edit the following sentences into proper sentences. Please help me with this.
>
> Yesterday, my manager assigned me some work to do, and today I completed that work. I have to inform my manger that I completed the task, and have attached the documents regarding the assignment.

Comment: In response to your version of the question: He's not really asking for anyone to “edit” the sentences that follow, but rather to help him express the information they contain to a third party. Nice work otherwise.

Comment: To "express the information," he had to edit them. I just threw that particular word (along with "to" and "the") in as one of multiple possible ways of resolving the meaning of that sentence.